# How to count elements of a column of a table having more than one values

Tags: sql, count

My question is: I have a table `Compose` that contains a column `emailID`. In this column, I have data like `abc@abc.com`, `def@abc.com, ghi@abc.com`.

Now whenever I count the number of elements of that column using `select count(*) from compose`, it shows me the answer: 2 elements, but it should return an answer of 3 elements. It should count `def@abc.com` and `ghi@abbc.com` as two elements which are in a single row. My problem is how can I make a row entry with comma in between as two entries count. Is there any SQL command for that?

Thank you

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing multiple values in a single column.

Comment: I guess: SUM(# of commas + 1). Depending on your dbms, you should use the available string functions to count the number of commas

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing multiple values in a single column.  That is just not the SQL way to store data.  Instead, you want another table, with one row per email.

That said, if you can't change the data model, then this approach will work for the specific problem you asked:

```
select sum(case when emails not like '%,%' then 1
                when emails not like '%,%,%' then 2
           end) as full_cnt
```

Comment: thanks for this. but how can i store the data on two different rows. i am using a text box in which user have to enter his email address. The thing is that it can send to multiple recipients also.So, if he writes abc@abc.com,def@abc.com then how can i seperate these two mails and store it in two different rows.

Comment: that's why i stored the recipients as whole

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in previous comment - **do not!** store data that you **needs to be processed** in single - hard-to-understand field. When storing really an single email you can also validate it before saving.

1. Make a child table "emails" that is bound to main table (normally with foreign key)
2. When user enters the data into textbox - you application should do the splitting and store individual emails that where spitted into "emails" table

   ```
   string[] emls = textBox.Text.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   ```
3. When presenting the data for user to edit you can compose the data from "emails" into single textbox.

Comment: then how to extract the data that is present inside emls?

Comment: [pseudocode] foreach(var em in emls) -> insert into emails (fieldName) values (em)